# User Notification

Tags: php, javascript, html, notifications

Curious about user notification techniques. Referring to simple stuff. For example, a user submit's a contact form. Once submitted, the user sees a message which says the form submission was successful.

Here is the question. How do you accomplish this (with PHP), without appending a string to the url? I ask this because I see more and more sites notifying users without using a GET query var in the url.

Are they just storing something in a global var somewhere and reading that/unsetting on read? What techniques are currently used to accomplish this?

**To add further, when the form is posted and saved:**

```
//The form has been processed, emailed, etc. Now redirect the user back to the page
//We redirect the user so that if they click refresh, the form doesn't re-submit.
//So without a query var in the url, who does the page no that a form was saved?
//Sessions are one solution, what if sessions are not being used?
header("Location:the_original_page.php");
```

Comment: see the note added to my answer about using the database instead of sessions to determine post success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: cookies (or sessions). Cookies are actually easier because their values are only populated in the subsequent request and they don't eat up your server space and you don't have to rely on sessions.

This kind of postponed messages are usually described as flash messages.

One particular implementation that I like is the [Note library](http://www.dingoframework.com/docs/note-library) of [Dingo Framework](http://www.dingoframework.com/).

Comment: I like this option. Plus, you can set the cookie with PHP on the server, and read it with Javascript on the client if you needed to. May be the best solution yet. As much as the database option works, this seems a bit resource intensive.

Answer (score 2):

An amazing technology called POST :)

Comment: Obviously. But after the form is submitted, a redirect happens sending the user back to the original page. So is the "technique" sending a success message via POST when posting back?

Comment: I don't think this is what the question implies.  Sounds like the OP is seeing things like `/page?success=1` in the querystring to indicate success.

Comment: @Michael, no GET var is in the URL in this situation.

Comment: @Chris: Well that wasn't exactly your question - I thought you were just referring to a success message on the page to which the form is submitted. In that case, it could be POST, but it's probably more likely that it's session variables.

Comment: Ok, so are session vars the only solution for something like this? I guess you could use Cookies, assuming the user has them enabled.

Comment: No, there are lots of solutions - you can use JavaScript, you can submit to the page with a `?do=submit-the-form` link or `action` attribute...

Comment: POST? does not answer the question in any way

Answer (score 2):

They're generally setting a session variable to indicate post success and checking for it when the next page loads:

```
// After handling the $_POST:
// Assume all data validated and inserted already and you have 
// set the variable $post_was_successful....
session_start();
if ($post_was_successful) {
  $_SESSION['post_success'] = TRUE;
}


// Upon loading the next page:
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['post_success']) {
  echo "you successfully submitted the form.";

  // Then remove the session variable so it isn't reused
  unset($_SESSION['post_success']);
}
else {
  // Whatever you need to say if it was a failure
  // or reload the form for resubmission or whatever..
}
```

This requires some sort of persistent storage.  If sessions are not being used (they probably should be), then you need to accomplish the same thing by checking the database when the page loads to see if the appropriate information is there.

Comment: True. What if you are not using Sessions?

Comment: @Chris if you're not using sessions and you need the state to persist across a page load, then you have to use a querystring param, as in your question!.  Sessions are necessary if this has to persist across a page load.

Comment: I imagine he'd want an else command in there to for if the post/submission fails to go through. Not sure where he would want to fit that in based on how he builds these pages with successful results and such. But it is probably wise to have a notifier saying the submission failed as well.

Comment: @Chris Actually I suppose you could also check the database on the next page load to see if it was successful, but using a session var is almost certainly going to be easier and more efficient.

Comment: @JackMcE I figured that was implied, but I added an `else` for clarification.

Comment: I probably shouldn't of directed that at you. Probably should of said that to the OP just as a reminder to at some point add it in somewhere. But still thanks for at least adding it in.

Answer (score 2):

ya typically in your save function you would do something like:

```
if(thingWasSaved) {
  NotifyUser("Your Thing was saved, awesome")
} else {
  NotifyUser("There was a problem saving your thing")
}
```

you could also do the same with a try catch statement etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a session variable that gets cleared when the data is retrieved

Example:

```
// when the form is processed successfully;

session_start();

$_SESSION['message'] = "Thank you for signing up";

// the redirect;
```

in the thank you page you can access the variable

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['message'])){
   $message = $_SESSION['message'];
   unset($_SESSION['message']); // delete the message
}
```

now you can use the message variable to see the message

Comment: This is true. Probably best method. But what if you are not using Sessions on your site? Such as a Wordpress site.

Comment: Do you mean like if you are sending the data through ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, they are probably using ajax

Comment: AJAX would make it easy :) But not all of these sites are using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and use it globally. ALso, post forms to empty (action="") so that way you can validate and save/send information all before determining what meessage to send, then give it to the Notifier class.

Then on every page, within the document have the print code.

eg.

```
<?
require_once('Notifier.class.php');
$Notifier = Notifier::getInstance();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    // VALIDATE DATA / SAVE DATA / EMAIL DATA
     if($saved == true){
        $Notifier->add('Thank you for your input!', 'success');
    } else {
        $Notifier->add('There was an error!', 'error');
    }
}

?>
<html>
<body>
<? $Notifier->_print(); ?>
<form name="contact" method="post" action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
```

You can do all kinds of cool things by doing it this way: form validation, sticky input, red-labled fields on erroneous inputs, form hiding on submission, and notification of everything. Here is an example of the Notification class:

```
<?
class Notifier{

    public static $instance;
    private $messages = array();

    private function __construct(){
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::instance)){
            self::instance = new Notifier();
        }
        return self::instance;
    }

    public function add($message, $class){
        $this->messages[] = '<p class='.$class.'>'.$message.'</p>';
    }

    public function _print(){
        if(!is_array($this->messages)){
            $this->messages = array($this->messages);
        }

        if(count($this->messages)){
            foreach($this->messages as $msg){
            print $msg;
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a revised version. It uses sessions and is a static class. Work great:

```
<?php
/// Notifier 3.0
class Notifier {

private function __construct() {
}

public static function add($message, $class = NULL) {
    $message_node = '<div class="notification'.(NULL !== $class ? ' '.$class : '').'"'.($this->click_to_dismiss ? ' onclick="this.style.display=\'none\'"' : '').'>'.$message.'</div>';
    $_SESSION[SESSION_NAMESPACE][SESSION_MESSAGES][] = $message_node;
}

public static function print() {
    while(!empty($_SESSION[SESSION_NAMESPACE][SESSION_MESSAGES])) {
        $message = array_shift($_SESSION[SESSION_NAMESPACE][SESSION_MESSAGES]);
        print $message;
        $message = NULL;
    }
}

private function _session_start() {
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        if(session_id() == "") {
            session_start();
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```